# Conditionally merge consecutive rows of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have an Input Dataframe that the following :

```
NAME    TEXT
Tim     Tim Wagner is a teacher.
Tim     He is from Cleveland, Ohio.
Frank   Frank is a musician.
Tim     He like to travel with his family
Frank   He is a performing artist who plays the cello.
Frank   He performed at the Carnegie Hall last year.
Frank   It was fantastic listening to him.
```

I want to concatenate TEXT column if the consecutive rows of NAME column have the same value.

**Output Dataframe:**

```
NAME    TEXT
Tim     Tim Wagner is a teacher.  He is from Cleveland, Ohio.
Frank   Frank is a musician
Tim     He like to travel with his family
Frank   He is a performing artist who plays the cello. He performed at the Carnegie Hall last year. It was fantastic listening to him.
```

Is using pandas shift, the best way to do this? Appreciate any help

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
grp = (df['Name'] != df['NAME'].shift()).cumsum().rename('group')
df.groupby(['NAME', grp], sort=False)['TEXT']\
  .agg(' '.join).reset_index().drop('group', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    NAME                                               TEXT
0    Tim  Tim Wagner is a teacher. He is from Cleveland,...
1  Frank                                Frank is a musician
2   Tim                  He likes to travel with his family
3  Frank  He is a performing artist who plays the cello....
```

Comment: Not sure how cumsum() will work on the text column (NAME). Also is grp the grouped dataframe from df['NAME'].shift().cumsum().rename('group')

Comment: @user14262559 You are right.  I mis-copied the original answer and when zabop corrected it I didn't catch the error.  Tak e a look a the updated solution.

Comment: Thanks @scott-boston that worked. I have a follow-up question. I want to aggregate 2 additional columns as well (START, END). New START will be from the first row that I am aggregate and new END will be from the last row aggregated. For eg: 


NAME    TEXT           START END
Tim     Tim Wagner is a teacher.          10  20.5
Tim     He is from Cleveland, Ohio.      20.5 40

Should be aggregated as :

NAME    TEXT             START  END
Tim     Tim Wagner is a teacher.  He is from Cleveland, Ohio. 10   40

Comment: @user14262559 Sure we can do that also, would mind creating a new question with this additional columns to be aggregrated.

Comment: sure will do. Thanks for the prompt response

Comment: 63886474 is the new one. @scott-benson that you very much for your help.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This code solved my problem.  Just add a comment about the 2nd line of code.  The origin version from @Scott-Boston somehow doesn't work for my script. The  following modification does, which also drop N/A values during the merge: `df = df.groupby([0, grp], sort=False).agg(lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna().astype(str))).reset_index().drop('group', axis=1)
`

Comment: Wonderful answer. Saved me a lot of time!!

Answer (score 0):

I went row by row and just created a new DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['Tim', 'Tim Wagner is a teacher.'],
['Tim', 'He is from Cleveland, Ohio.'],
['Frank', 'Frank is a musician'],
['Tim ', 'He likes to travel with his family'],
['Frank', 'He is a performing artist who plays the cello.'],
['Frank', 'He performed at the Carnegie Hall last year'],
['Frank', 'It was fantastic listening to him']], columns=['NAME', 'TEXT'])

col = ""
txt = ""
arr = []
con_ind = 0
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if col == row['NAME']:
        txt += ' ' + row['TEXT']
    else :
        if (i != 0):
            arr.append([col, txt])
        col = row['NAME']
        txt = row['TEXT']
        
if (txt != row['TEXT']):
    arr.append([col, txt])


print(pd.DataFrame(arr))
```

Comment: Thanks this works, Looks for a non-loop method as the dataframes are large